# Where is the engine oil filler tap on my Peugeot 504?

Tags: engine, maintenance, oil-change, peugeot

The engine oil is a bit low on my peugeot 504 (petrol 4 cylinders from 1979). I'm would like to top it up, but can't locate where oil filler tap is.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at some 504 engines, I see your confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is down the side of the engine, on the left-hand side... It would appear that the filler is part of the oil recirculation system, there should be a hose going down into a round thing, the top of which should pull off (with the hose still attached) to allow you to top it up...

[This site](http://www.504.org/ManuelUs74.htm) has a scan of the owner's manual, Pages 5 and 51 seem to be the most useful (although that's a relative statement!). It seems to be better illustrated in the [exploded parts diagram](http://www.504.org/CatPiecesDetachees.htm) on the same site - the fourth page of the second chapter. Images not hotlinked to avoid overwhelming the site in question...

Comment: I guess you are talking about this [thing](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46389739/peugeot.png) (red circle)?

Comment: Yep, that's the one - I think!

Comment: I've checked and that's correct